# Representable integer matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C, R \in \mathbb{Z}^n$. If there is an $n \times n$-matrix $M$ with all entries being integers such that the sum of the entries of column $k$ equals $C(k)$, and the sum of the entries of row $k$ equals $R(k)$, for all $k \in \{1,...,n\}$, we say that the pair $(C, R)$ is *representable*.

For $(C, R)$ to be representable, it is easy to see that we need $\sum_{i=1}^n C(i) = \sum_{i=1}^n R(i)$.

Does the converse hold?

Comment: For non-negative integer vectors, this is a consequence of the RSK correspondence (Knuth, "Permutations, Matrices, and Generalized Young Tableaux", Pacific J. Math., 1970). Perhaps you already know that.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question, but given $(C,R)$ with $\sum C(i)=\sum R(i)$, can't they be realized as representable via the upper-triangular matrix

$$M=\begin{bmatrix}C(1)&C(2)-R(2)&\ldots&C(n)-R(n)\\
&R(2)&&\\
&&\ddots&\\
&&&R(n)\end{bmatrix}$$
since the sum of the first row is $\sum C(i)-((\sum R(i))-R(1))=R(1)$?